# Preferred protocols to upload static files to your Apache server?

Tags: apache, security, administration, file-management

If you were the administrator of an Apache web server, what protocol(s) would you prefer to provide, for the web developers to upload static files (html/gif/css/...), with the goal of maximum security ?
If you were the web developer/graphic designer, what protocols would you prefer to be available at the Apache server, to upload static files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SCP is what I'd go with.

You can even use Filezilla for it and pretend it's unsecure FTP: http://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

SSH/SCP. It's simple, fast, free, and can be as secure as you want. Alternatives are FTP (hahahaha, yeah right) and POSTing files over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I give web developers instructions on using an sftp/scp client and a login shell using [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). That way they get their access to upload files, but I have fewer concerns about them doing bad things to the webserver.

Comment: Scponly can also be configured to use a chroot, disallowing users access to all other accounts, which is perfect for hosted environments.  It can be configured to allow Subversion access allowing developers to commit changes to or pull changes from a central repository.

Answer (score 0):

I use ssh config to limit users to sftp on a development server then use version control to review the changes and move them to production with got format-patch

Answer (score 0):

We deploy using Capistrano, which afaik does all its work via git (over SSH) - at least, in our deploy script it is.